# Excel subtract X days from date and then find last specific workday date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

here's my problem:

We have an Excel sheet at work in order to manage various tasks all set on individually specified timelines - we're talking hundreds of tasks per month with dates that are currently all being maintained manually.

Let's say we have Task A and that task has a Due Date. That Task is split into several subtasks, all with their individual due dates. Date 1 would then always be Due Date - 10 days, Date 2 would be Due Date - 20 days, Date 3 would be Due Date - 17 days and so on. This then creates a neat timeline of when everything needs to be done.

That in itself would be easy enough, problem is that all of these subtasks have to be done on a specific workday as well. Meaning that subtask 1 would not only have to be done Due Date - 10 days, but it would also have to fall on a Monday - if for whatever reason Due Date - 10 would happen to fall on like a Wednesday, it would have to subtract another 2 days. And then the real problem is that Date 2 and 3 each have to fall on different workdays and Task B has an entirely different schedule again.

Now, the first thing that came to my mind was attempting to just nest a couple IFs - and I've even managed to come up with a working formula for that. Problem here is that it's so stupidly long and (thanks Excel) utterly unreadable - if for some reason someone else had to change something about it or troubleshoot the entire file 1-2 years from now, they'd probably have to spend at least an hour reconstruct how the hell any of it actually worked. Which doesn't sound particularly appealing to us.

Here's a screenshot to help illustrating the situation: [image]
And here's a draft of the current formula that I'm really not happy with, despite it somewhat doing the job:
`=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(K2-VLOOKUP(B2,Table1,3,FALSE),11)>5,VLOOKUP(B2,Table1,5,FALSE)=0),(K2-VLOOKUP(B2,Table1,3,FALSE))-(WEEKDAY(K2-VLOOKUP(B2,Table1,3,FALSE),11)-5), IF(VLOOKUP(B2,Table1,5,FALSE)=0,K2-VLOOKUP(B2,Table1,3,FALSE), IF(WEEKDAY((K2-VLOOKUP(B2,Table1,3,FALSE)),11)=0,K2-VLOOKUP(B2,Table1,3,FALSE), (VLOOKUP(B2,Table1,5,FALSE)-WEEKDAY(K2-VLOOKUP(B2,Table1,3,FALSE),11))+K2-VLOOKUP(B2,Table1,3,FALSE))))`

My question is now: Does anyone have an idea how to solve this in a less confusing and unclear manner? I was trying to get something done using =CHOOSE() but ultimately ended up with the same problem of eventually having to resort to 7 IFs and dozens of LOOKUPs, making the final formula just as long. I wouldn't be disinclined towards some kind of helper table that asigns the last 7 days and their workdays to every single day of the year... but I don't think tossing another 20,000 calculated cells into a file that already has tens of thousands other calculated cells would really be a serviceable alternative... or make the situation any less obscure at all tbh.
So, anyone any idea how to go about this? Or is there really no realistic alternative than to use a bunch of IFs?

Edit: Forgot to mention that 1 special case:
There's also the situation when a date doesn't have to fall on a specific workday - in which case it's simply due date - X days. The problem here is that in those cases the dates could fall on a weekend, so the formula would have to move these dates to the previous Friday as well.

Comment: Yes, you can do it without all those `IF's`.  What workdays do the others have to fall on. And is the `-10` refer to ten days or ten **work**days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have some date and you want to "back up" ten days and then to the preceding Monday, unless the resultant date is a Monday.  The general formula would be something like:

```
=A2-10+1-WEEKDAY(A2-10-DOW)
```

Where DOW translates into

```
Sunday=0
Monday=1
Tuesday=2
...
```

You should be able to modify your formulas to use this algorithm for day of the week.

If the two tables are named `thisTable` and `keyTable`, the following `365`  formula is one way of implementing:

If your tables are as below, you can enter the formula in B2 and fill down and across.  The references should self-adjust and return the proper dates.

*Note that in keyTable, I enter the day of the week `DOW` as defined above, and not the textual date.*

```
=LET(dys,VLOOKUP(thisTable[@[Task]:[Task]],KeyTable,COLUMNS($A:A)*2,FALSE),
     dow,VLOOKUP(thisTable[@[Task]:{Task]],KeyTable,COLUMNS($A:A)*2+1,FALSE),
      due,thisTable[@[DueDate]:[DueDate]],
IF(dow="flexible",WORKDAY(due-dys+1,-1),due-dys+1-WEEKDAY(due-dys-dow)))
```

[image]

If you want to have the result be the closest workday, instead of the preceding workday, then you need to add two clauses to the `LET` function

- Calculate the subsequent workday date
- Then use an `IF` to return the closest one to the original target

eg:

```
=LET(dys,VLOOKUP(thisTable[@[Task]:[Task]],KeyTable,COLUMNS($A:A)*2,FALSE),
     dow,VLOOKUP(thisTable[@[Task]:[Task]],KeyTable,COLUMNS($A:A)*2+1,FALSE),
     due,thisTable[@[DueDate]:[DueDate]],
     dayPrev,IF(dow="flexible",WORKDAY(due-dys+1,-1),due-dys+1-WEEKDAY(due-dys-dow)),
     daySubseq,IF(dow="flexible",WORKDAY(due-dys+1,-1),due-dys+7-WEEKDAY(due-dys-1-dow)),
  IF((daySubseq-due+dys)>3,dayPrev,daySubseq))
```

[image]

Comment: The formula itself is working, I forgot to mention a special problem case though: Some subtasks don't have a designated workday, meaning it's just due date - 10 days. This could naturally lead to dates falling onto weekends, in which case the final date would have to be moved to the previous Friday. The overall problem is that the repeated referencing inevitably leads to multi-row formulas - I was hoping for some kind of magical matrix solution that would have me put in all my references and rules once, but I'm kinda doubting something like that is possible in Excel.

Comment: @PeterParker You can do this with a single formula, with your lookup table. For your special case, you'd use the WORKDAY formula. What version of Excel?

Comment: O365 here, what would that WORKDAY formula have to look like then?

Comment: @PeterParker If you want to back up 10 days, but then to the preceding Friday if the result is a weekend, something like `=WORKDAY(A1-9,-1)`

Comment: That actually did the trick, tyvm - I'd mark your post as solution, but I don't have enough rep to do so yet. The formula is still a bit convoluted, but I think that's just about the best I could hope for - for anyone stumbling across this in the future: =IF(XLOOKUP([@AK],Tab_Aufw[AK],Tab_Aufw[Landd])=Data!$AC$7,WORKDAY([@LT]-XLOOKUP([@AK],Tab_Aufw[AK],Tab_Aufw[Briefing])+1,-1),[@LT]-XLOOKUP([@AK],Tab_Aufw[AK],Tab_Aufw[Briefing])+1-WEEKDAY([@LT]-XLOOKUP([@AK],Tab_Aufw[AK],Tab_Aufw[Briefing])+1-XLOOKUP([@AK],Tab_Aufw[AK],Tab_Aufw[S1])+6))

Comment: @PeterParker Glad to help, and glad you figured out a solution that works with my hints.

Comment: @PeterParker I've added a formula that also seems to work, with the tables I set up from your examples.

Comment: Hello friend, thanks for the LET formula - that is indeed also working. We've stumbled across a little problem though: In our current approach we're always calculating backwards - meaning if a Task's date happens to be Monday but is supposed to be a Wednesday, we always subtract 5 days. What we'd actually want in this case though, is to just go 2 days forward instead - so going to the nearest supposed workday, not the last supposed workday. Happen to have any hints on how to deal with that?

Comment: @PeterParker You'd need to use a different formula to find the subsequent workday, and then choose the value that is closest.  The formula for the subsequent workday is `theDate+7-WEEKDAY(theDate-1+DOW)`.  The `LET` function will be quite useful here.

Comment: @PeterParker see edited question for handling closest workday

Comment: And that does the trick again. Tyvm kind stranger.